# How do i use SqlTransaction across multipe methods

Tags: c#, using, sqlcommand, sqltransaction

Let's assume we have an Object A which can be deleted an Object B which hold a forendkey from A

If you want to deleted A, you have to delete the forendkey from B first and then you can delete A but if something goes wrong it should be rolled back but i also want to use the delete forendkey from B independent but at the moment i don't know how to achieve this

my current idea :

```
    public void DeleteA(Object a)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
        {
            con.open();

            using (SqlTransaction tr = con.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    DeleteAfromAllB(a, con, tr);

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("STP_A_Delete", con))
                    {
                        cmd.Transaction = tr;

                        // some parameters
                        // some sort of Execute
                        // e.g.: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    tr.Commit();
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    //ExceptionHandling
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void DeleteAfromAllB(Object a, SqlConnection con, SqlTransaction tr)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("STP_B_Delete_Referenc_To_A", con))
            {
                cmd.Transaction = tr;

                // some parameters
                // some sort of Execute
                // e.g.: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            //ExceptionHandling
        }
    }       

    public void DeleteAfromAllB(Object a)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
        {
            con.open();

            using (SqlTransaction tr = con.BeginTransaction())
            {
                DeleteAfromAllB(a,con,tr);

                tr.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

but like you can see this is pretty ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call

```
public void DeleteAfromAllB(Object a)
```

does not need to pass the SqlConnection as you can reference from tr.Connection. So you just need the SqlTransaction as parameter. So for your original question, yes I think passing in the SqlTransaction is the way to go. Personally I prefer this way because you can easily trace the call stack / scope of the transaction (i.e. where the transaction started/finished).

Another alternative is to use a TransactionScope.

E.g.

```
private void DeleteAfromAllB(Object a)
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection())
    {
        con.open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("STP_B_Delete_Referenc_To_A", con))
        {
            // some parameters
            // some sort of Execute
            // e.g.: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}

public void DeleteAfromAllB_TopLevel(Object a)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        try
        {
            DeleteAfromAllB(a);

            // The Complete method commits the transaction. If an exception has been thrown, 
            // Complete is not  called and the transaction is rolled back.
            scope.Complete();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //ExceptionHandling
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, they way you have it written, if an exception is thrown in DeleteAFromAllB, it doesn't get rethrown, and scope.Complete gets called  in the TopLevel call...

I believe the exception handling should be done in the TopLevel call.

Comment: Hi John yes you are correct the handling in the child should be removed and moved to parent. Fixed thanks. Looked like I had a bad copy pasta in there... the try and catch weren't lined up!